# Visual Studio on Mac (v7.1) - Cannot deploy/publish to Azure

Tags: azure, publish, azure-deployment, visual-studio-mac

I cannot publish anymore my app with publish profile to Azure after updating my Visual Studio on Mac to version 7.1. I'm getting the following error:

> /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.3/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish/build/netstandard1.0/PublishTargets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(136,5): error : Package/Publish task Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.Tasks.MsDeploy.VSMSDeploy failed to load Web Deploy assemblies. Microsoft Web Deploy is not correctly installed on this machine. Microsoft Web Deploy v3 or higher is recommended.
>       0 Warning(s)
>       1 Error(s)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I installed .Net Core v2.0 on my mac, changed the target framework in my app to .netcore2.0 and now I'm able to publish my app to Azure again.
I don't have a clue why it is.

Answer (score -1):

As your error suggest to have Web deploy v3 or higher, please download it: https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=30436

Comment: I'm on Mac. I don't think the error relates to the web deploy.